# Bejeweled type logic on a 2d array

Tags: lua, logic

I'm trying to wrap my head around the logic and I can't think of the best way of doing it.

I have a 2d array array[10][6] 10 is the number of columns and 6 is the number of rows. I want to check for 3 or more matching items within the array. Does anyone know of a good example or have an idea for a solution? I've looked at some resources online but all the ones I've seen really lack comments and are hard to read.

The items would create a match if there are 3 or more side by side in the row or 3 on top of each other in a column.

Comment: And just *how* would they match?  By row, by column, or by m by n box?

Comment: They would be able to be matched by row or column. If there are 3 or more side by side in the row it would count as a match or 3 on top of each other in a column it would be a match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same idea as @Dave, maybe easier to understand (`t` is your 2D array):

```
for y=1,6 do -- for each row
  for x=1,10-2 do -- for each possible horizontal triplet
    if t[x+1][y] == t[x][y] and t[x+2][y] == t[x][y] then
      -- match
    end
  end
end

for x=1,10 do -- for each column
  for y=1,6-2 do -- for each possible vertical triplet
    if t[x][y+1] == t[x][y] and t[x][y+2] == t[x][y] then
      -- match
    end
  end
end
```

It may not be the fastest algorithm but it is the simplest one and the potential performance gains of anything else are not worth the increase in complexity IMO.

EDIT: I did not realize Dave was the OP :) So yes, that method works.

Comment: This is much cleaner I will use this in my code. The x and y makes so much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

yI'm not sure if this is the best way of doing it but it's what I got to work. This is lua code

```
function checkWinningsFunction()
    --Check x axis for matches
    for i=1,6 do
        for n=1,8 do

            if(reelImages[n][i].value == reelImages[n+1][i].value and reelImages[n+1][i].value == reelImages[n+2][i].value) then
                --Match
            end

        end
    end

    --Check y axis for matches
    for i=1,4 do
        for n=1,10 do

            if(reelImages[n][i].value == reelImages[n][i+1].value and reelImages[n][i+1].value == reelImages[n][i+2].value) then
                --Match
            end

        end
    end
end
```